# The parameterized query '(@lastName nvarchar(4000),@firstName nvarchar(4000),@middleName ' expects the parameter '@lastName', which was not supplied

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dg1.Rows)
{
    string constring = @"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=RecruitmentDB;User ID=sa";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ApplicantFamilyBackground(lastName,firstName,middleName,relationship,applicantcode) VALUES(@lastName, @firstName, @middleName, @relationship, @applicantcode)", con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", row.Cells["dglastname"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", row.Cells["dgfirstname"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@middleName", row.Cells["dgmiddlename"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@relationship", row.Cells["dgrelationship"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@applicantcode",row.Cells["dgapplicantcode"].Value = lblapplicantcode.Text.ToString());

            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You cant pass parameters to a sql command like that' You need to use a stored procedure.

Comment: how?????????????

Comment: commandtext?............

Comment: Create a stored procedure in SQL to handle your insert logic. Then, when you create your SqlCommand, set CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure. Then, instead of typing the SQL into the command text l ike you've done, you'll specify the stored procedure instead.

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't realize you could in fact pass parameters in this way to a sql query.

Comment: @Xedni It's by far the easiest way to deal with unsafe data in databases.  No issues of sanitation, no issues of encoding characters that are unsafe in command strings.

Comment: how to copy datagridview1 row1 cell1 to other row same cell automatic?

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception occurs because the value of `@lastName`, as pulled from `row.Cells["dglastname"].Value`, is `null`, therefore the value of the `SqlParameter` must be set to `DBNull.Value`.

One way of fixing it would be to replace the parameters initialization as follows:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", row.Cells["dglastname"].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", row.Cells["dgfirstname"].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@middleName", row.Cells["dgmiddlename"].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@relationship", row.Cells["dgrelationship"].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@applicantcode", row.Cells["dgapplicantcode"].Value = lblapplicantcode.Text != null ? lblapplicantcode.Text.ToString() : DBNull.Value);
```

Comment: how do i remove the last row? it adds in my db